# Pine Script - 3 Take profits, 1 SL and 1 Trailing Stop Calculated by Price

Tags: pine-script, exit, multi-level, trailing

I have read a dozen posts and tried many things in TV, but I can't seem to understand how PineScript works regarding strategy exits. I have an indicator-calculated-Price for each Level I want to use as an Exit (1 stoploss, 3 take profits and a trailing stop )

here is an example of the first 4 levels:

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0)

strategy.exit( "SL" ,from_entry="Long" ,qty_percent = 100 , stop= STOP )

strategy.exit( "tp1" , from_entry="Long", qty_percent=10, limit= k_vol_upper  )

strategy.exit( "tp2" , from_entry="Long", qty_percent=50, limit= AF_midLevel  )

strategy.exit( "tp3" , from_entry="Long", qty_percent=50, limit=a_AF_level4   )
```

the problem is the take profit levels don't work, only the stoploss, that's unless I change the "stop" order from "exit" to "close", and put an event instead of a level, like so:

```
strategy.close( "SL" ,from_entry="Long" , qty_percent = 100, when= xxx  )
```

in which case I get closed out late... the price has gone trough the SL level and closed there, but at least it gets the TakeProfit levels to work, with the "stop=" they just don't, well sort off, exits seem the be executed only on closes above the levels, I see levels broken by wicks every where not executed by the strategy, entries and exits, only on closes.

The las thing is the Trailing stop, which should follow a Bollinger band once the price has reached tp2

Anyways, I believe the logics should be simple enough and once you've seen it, its a done deal, I wish there was a YouTube video explaining this but I've looked for it.

Comment: Would you mind sharing more of the code? I need to see how your tp's and stops are calculated in full. If you edit the question with more code and comment here to let me know I can help you out for sure. Cheers